# Activity minimize in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Im working on offline login based application using SQLite. For the purpose of security i need to move to login activity if the app has minimized.  i tried this code in onPause function

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(dashboard.this, login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

    super.onPause();
}
```

when i try to move from that activity to another also it moves to the login activity. i hope when im moving to another activity current activity is set to paused. that's why it moves to login activity.

Comment: Define "minimize". There's no such thing in Android. An application is either dead, on foreground or on background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set a Boolean to handle loginActivity:

```
boolean mustGoToLoginActivity=true;
```

when you want to go to another Activity first set this boolean to false for example:

```
public void goToAnotherActivity() {
      mustGoToLoginActivity=false;
      //...
      startActivity(anotherActivity);
}
```

and in `onResume()` method set it to `true`.
Then in `onPause()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    if(mustGoToLoginActivity){
       Intent intent = new Intent(dashboard.this, login.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
    }

    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this scenario will not work. What you can do is use a static boolean to achieve the behavior like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   static Boolean navigateToLogin =false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (navigateToLogin) {
            move();
            navigateToLogin =false;
        }
    }

    private void move() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        navigateToLogin = true;
    }
}
```